# Error al enviar parámetros a una vista

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:

> TypeError: data is undefined in template line 16 and index line 10

Aquí esta mi código intento pasar el data por parametro pero me sale error

Este es el servidor:

```
app.get('/catalogo', (req, res, next) => {
    //service.getAll();

    req.getConnection((err, shop) => {
        shop.query('SELECT * FROM store', (err, row) => {
            if(err) throw err;

            res.render('index',{data: row,title: 'catalogo de productos'});
        });
    });
});
```

Este es el index usando page.js:

```
var template = require('./template'),
    yo = require('yo-yo'),
    empty = require('empty-element'),
    title = require('title'),
    page = require('page');

page('/catalogo', (ctx, next) => {
    title('Catalogo de Productos');
    var mag = document.getElementById('main-container');
    empty(mag).appendChild(template);
});
```

y este es el template usando yo-yo.js:

```
var yo = require('yo-yo');

var el = yo`<div id="signup-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>Mostar productos</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>` 

var es = yo`<h4>No hay registros en la base de datos</h4>`;

module.exports = function (data) {
    if(data.length){
        return el;
    }else{
        return console.log('no hay articulos');
    }
}
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Por favor [edit] la pregunta indicando en qué parte de este código obtienes el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en el la línea del if, antes de chequear `data.length` deberías chequear que `data` existe, por ejemplo de esta forma:

```
if(data && data.length){
    return el;
}else{
    return console.log('no hay articulos');
}
```

Si data es `undefined` la condición da `false` y al ser un `&&` no chequea el `data.length` que es lo que está haciendo explotar el código

Comment: gracias amigo  otra pregunta ya aregle el error pero ahora no haya la forma de mostrar la data que saque de la base de datos ya intente usando un for in con un appendChild y con un ineerHTML pero un no me muestra lo que tengo en la base de datos y si lo mando a imprimir por consola me aparece asi :

Comment: (1) […]
​
0: Object { title: "qwfqf", pricing: 34, description: "afaf", … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: []
​​

Comment: module.exports = function template(local) { 
  if(local.data && local.data.length){
console.log(local.data); 
return ${local.data.title} 
       ${local.data.pricing} 
       ${local.data.description} 
       ${local.data.image}}}

Comment: Esto iría en otra pregunta, el código no se entiende muy bien en los comentarios, pero lo que creo que pasa es que la variable `local.data` es un arreglo por lo que para acceder a las propiedades deberías hacer `local.data[0].title` `local.data[0].pricing`, etc.
Si te sirvió la respuesta marcala como aceptada así los que entren a mirar saben que es correcta

Comment: gracias si me sirvio